# Пример верстки под full-ajax сайт

Tags: ajax, html, вёрстка, javascript

Хочу научиться технологии ajax, и хотел бы посмотреть на примеры верстки под full-ajax сайты/панели администрирования (админки). 
Full-ajax подразумевает что весь HTML загружается только один раз в самом начале работы, а в дальнейшем клиент общается с сайтом только через XML/JSON.

Если есть примеры такой верстки, подскажите пожалуйста.

Спасибо.

Comment: >подразумевает что весь HTML загружается только один раз в самом начале работы

плохая идея, используйте темплейты и грузите их динамически

Comment: и кешируйте в localStorage

Да и вообще вопрос некорректен, верстается не сайт, а шаблоны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail, Facebook, VK, Google Image Search